# Change some Rows in excel to Column

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula

I have a CSV file in the format like below,

[image]

I need to import the data from the csv into Salesforce DB.It has to insert records in to 4 different tables that are related

```
Card 
  -->Section       
    --> Question 
       --> Answer
```

I need to normalize the table like instead of having the Multiple answers appearing in the same row I need to have each answers in its own row like

[image]

It is not necessarily I have only two answers in a row, it can even have 4 or 5 answers. If that is the case I need to add one row for each answers. Is this something doable through excel formulas. Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way to do this is using Power Query, hold down the first three columns and right click unpivot other columns.

[image]

it even works when the number of columns increased.

[image]

Change the data in a table and open a blank query from data tab. When the Power Query editor opens add the following in the advance editor hit ok, close and load to a new sheet or existing sheet as you prefer.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Card Name", type text}, {"Sec Name", type text}, {"Question Text", type text}, {"Answer 1", type text}, {"Answer 2", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Card Name", "Sec Name", "Question Text"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Value", "Answer"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

Comment: I tried the suggestion hear and it help.. Can you please help with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75716657/changing-some-rows-of-the-csv-file-in-to-column-for-data-load

Answer (score 2):

### Unpivot (Excel Formula)

[image]

```
=LET(Data,A2:G6,rCols,3,
    rData,TAKE(Data,,rCols),vData,TAKE(Data,,rCols-COLUMNS(Data)),
    cSeq,SEQUENCE(,rCols),
DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(ROWS(rData)),LAMBDA(rRes,rRow,
    LET(vrData,INDEX(vData,rRow),vfData,TOCOL(FILTER(vrData,vrData<>"")),
VSTACK(rRes,HSTACK(INDEX(rData,SEQUENCE(ROWS(vfData),,rRow,0),cSeq),vfData))))),1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this for the case of two answers, for more replace `2` in the formula accordingly and adjust the answer range.

```
=HSTACK(CHOOSEROWS(A2:C5, INT(SEQUENCE(2*ROWS(A2:C5),,0)/2+1)),TOCOL(D2:E5))
```

[image: output]

If you have a variable number of answers. For example, some row with `4` answers and some other row with `5`. Expand the answer range to its maximum, let's say `n` and then filter the result by removing rows with empty answers.

For example, here the case of `n=2`, but removing empty answers:

```
=LET(n, 2, in, A2:C5, ans, TOCOL(D2:E5), ansCol, COLUMNS(in)+1,
 out, HSTACK(CHOOSEROWS(in, INT(SEQUENCE(n*ROWS(in),,0)/n+1)),ans),
 FILTER(out, INDEX(out,, ansCol)<>0))
```