# Changing some Rows of the csv file in to Column for data load

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula, pivot, pivot-table

I had a CSV file in the format like below,

| Card Name | Sec Name | Question Text | Answer 1 | Answer 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Specialists Offline | Customer Satisfaction | Does the Bill | Yes | No |
| Specialists Offline | Customer Satisfaction | Do Invoicing Term | Yes | No |
| Specialists Offline | Customer Satisfaction | Have all appropriate Line | TRUE | FALSE |

To normalize the table in the below format

| Card Name | Sec Name | Question Text | Answer |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Specialists Offline | Customer Satisfaction | Does the Bill | Yes |
| Specialists Offline | Customer Satisfaction | Does the Bill | No |
| Specialists Offline | Customer Satisfaction | Do Invoicing Term | Yes |
| Specialists Offline | Customer Satisfaction | Do Invoicing Term | No |
| Specialists Offline | Customer Satisfaction | Have all appropriate Line | TRUE |
| Specialists Offline | Customer Satisfaction | Have all appropriate Line | FALSE |

I used the query like below with the help of the experts, it works great

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Card Name", type text}, {"Sec Name", type text}, {"Question Text", type text}, {"Answer 1", type text}, {"Answer 2", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Card Name", "Sec Name", "Question Text"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Value", "Answer"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

But now the table format has changed that the each Answer has attributes associated with it like below

| Sec Name | Question Text | Answer 1 | Answer 1 Score | Answer 2 | Answer 2 Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Customer Satisfaction | Does the Bill | Yes | 10 | No | 0 |
| Customer Satisfaction | Do Invoicing Term | Yes | 5 | No | 1 |
| Customer Satisfaction | Have all appropriate Line | TRUE | 3 | FALSE | 0 |

Since each answers have scores associated with it , I need each row with Answers and Score

| Sec Name | Question Text | Answer | Answer Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Customer Satisfaction | Does the Bill | Yes | 10 |
| Customer Satisfaction | Does the Bill | No | 0 |
| Customer Satisfaction | Do Invoicing Term | Yes | 5 |
| Customer Satisfaction | Do Invoicing Term | No | 1 |
| Customer Satisfaction | Have all appropriate Line | TRUE | 3 |
| Customer Satisfaction | Have all appropriate Line | FALSE | 0 |

So the answer record can be inserted with their scores associated that way it can be easily inserted in to Salesforce. I am very new to the Pivot queries any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
let
    TableOne = Table.AddIndexColumn(Table.RemoveColumns(Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content], {"Sec Name", "Question Text"}, "Attribute", "Value"),{"Attribute"}), "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    TableTwo = Table.AddIndexColumn(Table.RemoveColumns(TableOne,{"Index"}), "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    Source = Table.NestedJoin(TableOne, {"Index"}, TableTwo, {"Index"}, "Table2", JoinKind.Inner),
    #"Expanded Table2" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "Table2", {"Value"}, {"Table2.Value"}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded Table2", each Number.IsOdd([Index])),
    #"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"Sec Name", "Question Text", "Table2.Value", "Value", "Index"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{"Index"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Table2.Value", "Answer"}, {"Value", "Answer Score"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

The above is a consolidation of 3 main UI stages:

(1) Create a new query from Table1 on the worksheet, select the first 2 columns and 'Unpivot Other Columns', and then add an Index column (starting from 0)

(2) Reference the query at (1), and add an Index column (starting from 1)

(3) 'Merge as New' the queries at (1) and (2), using an inner join on the index columns added to (1) and (2), and filter for odd numbers in the Index column (you have to apply a sample filter in the UI, and then edit the formula bar to use the `Number.IsOdd()` syntax) - the rest is just removing, re-naming, and re-ordering columns
(if you have similar questions in future it would be in your interest to tag them with `powerquery`)

Comment: Thank you so much.. I thought I could try this with my actual table with the sample I posted above.. But this way advanced query for me to understand :-( If I can post my original table structure in another question can you please guide me

Comment: @user4912134, I've edited my answer to include the broad UI actions that result in the syntax I originally posted

Comment: Thank you, Do you think same approach would work in the table https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75717364/normalize-the-table-by-changing-some-rows-in-to-column

Comment: @user4912134, it was a bit more involved, but I've just posted an answer there, although you'll probably get a better answer from someone else, as the PQ knowledgeable people will have visibility of it, by virtue of the PQ tag