# Normalize the table by changing some rows in to Column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot, pivot-table, powerquery

Below sample table has a Section with Questions and the possible answers that each questions can have, all in the single row.. Each question can have between 1 to 4 answers.

| Sec Name | Question Text | Answer 1 | Answe1 Autofail | Answer 1 Score | Answer 2 | Answe2 Autofail | Answer 2 Score | Answer 3 | Answer3 Autofail | Answer3 score | Answer 4 | Answer4 Autofail | Answer4 score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Customer Satisfaction | Does the Bill | The syllabus lists points | FALSE | 1 | The syllabus lists | FALSE | 1 | The wrong column | FALSE | 0 | There is no total | FALSE | 0 |
| Customer Satisfaction | Do Invoicing Term | Yes | FALSE | 5 | No | FALSE | 0 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Customer Satisfaction | Have all appropriate Line | There is an ISBN | FALSE | 1 | There is no ISBN | FALSE | 0 | The ISBN number is listed | FALSE | 0 |  |  |  |

I need to import the data in to Salesforce database and I need to normalize the structure like each row can have Section, Question and One Answer and its attribute like AutoFail and Score. Below is the example of the normalized table with each answers in the row

| Sec Name | Question Text | Answer | Answe Autofail | Answer Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Customer Satisfaction | Does the Bill | The syllabus lists points | FALSE | 1 |
| Customer Satisfaction | Does the Bill | The syllabus lists | FALSE | 1 |
| Customer Satisfaction | Does the Bill | The wrong column | FALSE | 0 |
| Customer Satisfaction | Does the Bill | There is no total | FALSE | 0 |
| Customer Satisfaction | Do Invoicing Term | Yes | FALSE | 5 |
| Customer Satisfaction | Do Invoicing Term | No | FALSE | 0 |
| Customer Satisfaction | Have all appropriate Line | There is an ISBN | FALSE | 1 |
| Customer Satisfaction | Have all appropriate Line | There is no ISBN | FALSE | 0 |
| Customer Satisfaction | Have all appropriate Line | The ISBN number is listed | FALSE | 0 |

I am not so familiar with Powerquery or pivot table. Can anyone please help me how can I normslize this.. Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've tagged this question appropriately, one of the experts will probably provide shorter syntax

```
let
    TableOne = Table.AddIndexColumn(Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content], {"Sec Name", "Question Text"}, "Attribute", "Value"), "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type),
    TableTwo = Table.AddIndexColumn(TableOne, "Index.1", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    MergeOne = Table.AddIndexColumn(Table.ExpandTableColumn(Table.NestedJoin(TableOne, {"Index"}, TableTwo, {"Index.1"}, "Table2", JoinKind.Inner), "Table2", {"Value"}, {"Value.1"}), "Index.1", 3, 1, Int64.Type),
    Output = Table.RenameColumns(Table.RemoveColumns(Table.SelectRows(Table.ExpandTableColumn(Table.NestedJoin(MergeOne, {"Index.1"}, TableOne, {"Index"}, "Table2", JoinKind.LeftOuter), "Table2", {"Value"}, {"Value.2"}), each Number.Mod([Index],3) = 1),{"Attribute", "Index", "Index.1"}),{{"Value", "Answer"}, {"Value.1", "Answer Autofail"}, {"Value.2", "Answer Score"}})
in
    Output
```

From the UI perspective, this involves all the same steps as your last question, plus an additional step of merging (a left-outer join) of the first merge with the first table, and then filtering that result for values where the modulus of the current index and 3 is equal to 1

Answer (score 3):

Above answers work fine

The fastest method which also preserves row order that I've found is

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
leading=2, groupsof=3,
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each List.Split( List.RemoveFirstN(Record.ToList( _),leading), groupsof) ),
#"Added Custom0" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom0", each Text.Combine(List.FirstN(Record.ToList(_),leading),"|")),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Added Custom0",{"Custom0", "Custom"}),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandListColumn( #"Removed Other Columns", "Custom"),
#"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Expanded Custom", {"Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), "|"), type text}),
#"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Extracted Values",{"Custom0", "Custom"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.None),"Custom"),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Merged Columns", "Custom", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.Csv), List.FirstN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),leading+groupsof))
in #"Split Column by Delimiter"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Excel functions, assuming O365. Put the following formula in `A7`:

```
=LET(in,A2:N4, gr,3, q,4, seq,SEQUENCE(q,,1,0), h,{"Sec Name","Question Text",
 "Answer","Answe Autofail","Answer Score"}, PIVOT, LAMBDA(x,
  HSTACK(REPT(INDEX(x,{1,2}),seq),WRAPROWS(DROP(x,,2),gr))),
 y,REDUCE(h,SEQUENCE(ROWS(in)),LAMBDA(ac,i,VSTACK(ac,PIVOT(INDEX(in,i,))))),
 z, TAKE(TAKE(y,,-gr),,1), FILTER(y, z<>""))
```

Here is the output:
[image: output]

We use `REDUCE/VSTACK` pattern. Check my answer to this question for more information: [how to transform a table in Excel from vertical to horizontal but with different length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74477320/how-to-transform-a-table-in-excel-from-vertical-to-horizontal-but-with-different/74497691#74497691). The user `LAMBDA` function `PIVOT` does the pivot for each row on each iteration of `REDUCE`. The names: `gr` (number of columns per answer's information) and `q` (number of questions we have), control how to organize the information. The last line is just to remove empty answers.